# Scala equivalent of java.util.stream

Tags: java, scala, stream

Is there an Scala type (probably a trait) similar to [`java.util.stream.Stream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html)?

(I am using the better-supported Java 7, so Java 8's `Stream` is not available to me.)

Specifically, it must be generically typed, be iterable in some way, and be closeable.

```
try {
  stream.foreach(println)
  }
} finally {
  stream.close()
}
```

A solution in the standard libraries would be preferred, though something in another library would be acceptable.

Comment: I do not get why they vote down a good question? may be it does not make sense to them, yet it make sense to you. instead of being helpful they just vote down

Comment: Yeah, @KickButtowski, I've seen it happen quite a bit recently, to myself but also others. Very strange.

Comment: Is [`scala.collection.immutable.Stream`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.1/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Stream) not acceptable?

Comment: @univerio, it cannot be closed to release underlying resources (sockets, file handles, etc.)

Comment: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.1/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Stream

Comment: And you don't want to subclass it and just add a `close()` method?

Comment: @univerio, it looks like I'll probably do that.

Answer (score 4):

For collections, all collections in Scala can be used as if they are streams. In Scala the operators on `Iterable` / `Iterator` are lazily applied for example and you also have [Views](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_42.html) and [Stream](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.1/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Stream) (`Stream` is a lazily evaluated `List` and does memoization of the traversed values, so if you want memoization you can use a stream, but because of the memory requirements this it tricky for working with infinite streams - still it's pretty cool).

As you might have noticed however, this doesn't take care of all cases, because the stream could be a stream of data coming from a network socket, file handle and so on. So one needs to dispose of the underlying resources used.

I do not know of a direct equivalent, however I must also mention that I do not like Java's streams, because Java's streams are for processing iterable sequences, which means that their current design is pull-based. This may change in the future, but when processing streams, especially streams involving I/O, it's better to go non-blocking and asynchronous, therefore I prefer push based approaches, like [Iteratees](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/Iteratees), or the Reactive Extensions (Rx) pattern.

A lot is going on in the Scala/Java ecosystem in this regard. There is [RxJava](https://github.com/Netflix/RxJava), which is an Rx.NET port. There's also [Akka Streams](http://typesafe.com/blog/typesafe-announces-akka-streams), part of the [Reactive Streams](http://www.reactive-streams.org/) effort to specify an interoperable protocol for back-pressure - in the experimental/alpha stage.

And a shameless promotion - I'm working on [Monifu](http://www.monifu.org), an Rx implementation for Scala, that does back-pressure and that will also be integrated with the "Reactive Streams" protocol. And I also think it's already in a better shape and more idiomatic than the RxScala adaptor of RxJava, but since I'm the author, take that with a grain of salt :-)

Comment: there's also `Stream[T]` in Scala, just for the record.

Comment: @ErikAllik yes, but it's a different kind of stream. `Stream[T]` does lazy evaluation when applying operations on it, HOWEVER the big difference is that `Stream[T]` does memoization of the traversed values - being basically a lazily evaluated `List[T]`. This has value, if you want memoization, but it makes it unsuitable for processing infinite streams and thus it's in no way an equivalent. The closest equivalent to Java's stream is actually `Iterable[T]`.

Comment: @ErikAllik I've added a mention to it for completeness. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I'm aware of the differences you mentioned; just thought it would be worth mentioning; also, I think `Stream` is OK even for infinite streams if you don't keep references to the original head of the stream indefinitely. This might not be sufficiently performant though in some performance critical situations but might help design simpler algorithms in some other cases where short-term memoization is useful.

Comment: @ErikAllik yep, you're right, I already added a mention for it. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Agreed with most points. In this case, I am getting results from `java.sql.ResultSet`. JDBC drivers don't use asynchronous I/O.